# The strict equality operator and the not equal. Why they are not equal

Tags: javascript

I am at the start of my adventure in JS so I have a question. I created a little program that asks for your name and after that it prints out. And I'm wondering why these 2 sequences don't give me the same result. If I don't type anything this program should not print anything, but in the first case it prints and I don't get why it does.

```
do {
  var name = prompt("Who are you?");
} while (name === false);
console.log(name);
```

---

```
do {
  var name = prompt("Who are you?");
} while (!name);
console.log(name);
```

Thank you :)

Comment: prompt never returns false, so there ya go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompt returns a string, so the name variable is a string.

For === to work, both sides need to be the same type.

In this case, the left side is a string and the right side is not.

Comment: Thank you very much :). Now i got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

[`prompt()` will never return `false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt).

It may return an empty string, or `null` (if Cancel/ESC are used) -- either of which would satisfy `while (! name)` -- but neither of those is strictly equal to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt:

> Syntax
>
> result = window.prompt(text, value);
>
> result is a string containing the text entered by the user, or the value null.

Change your `=== false` to `=== null` and give it another try.  Bottom line, `window.prompt` will not return a boolean value, so your strict equality check fails.

Answer (score 0):

**Comparing** a value to a boolean is different from **converting** a value to a boolean.

`x === false` is literally testing whether `x` has the value `false`. But `!x` will *convert* `x` to boolean. So these are the two different operations that are performed:

```
// if (x === false)
(x === false) === true

// if (!x)
(!Boolean(x) === true)
```

The next piece of information is to know how different types of values are converted to boolean values. This is defined the [**spec**](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2). Here is an excerpt:

> `null`: `false`
>
> `undefined`: `false`
>
> String: The result is `false` if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is `true`.

If you don't provide a value, then `name` will be an *empty string*, which *converts* to the boolean `false`, but is not the value `false`.

Comment: Thank you. I got the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you want to run the script while `name` is **null** rather than false right?

Also, about the equals, note that

```
true == 1; // correct!
"2" == 2; // correct!
```

While

```
true === 1; // false
"2" === 2; // false
```

This is because `===` means identically equal. `==` will try to convert either side to any equivalent value before the comparison occurs.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1pq98tza/5/)